# How to add spinning force to unity2d game

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am creating an obstacle-avoiding game in Unity where you must avoid spinning obstacles to survive since my player is moving via physics I want my obstacles to be moving using physics so they collide correctly. I have tried using things such as AddTorque but that makes the objects keep spinning faster and faster and is not what I want. Does anyone know a way to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution might be affecting the `Rigidbody2D rotation` property directly like so:

```
public float rotationSpeed = 1.0f;
private Rigidbody2D _rigidBody2D;

void Start()
{
    _rigidBody2D = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
}

void FixedUpdate()
{
    // Rotate rigidbody every frame
    rigidBody2D.rotation += rotationSpeed;
}
```